# input "datetime-local" > js code that can update the current time automatically without having to click and select

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am trying to create a script that can update the current time automatically in the datetime-local input without having to click and selecting the current time. this is the code that i am working with to have the input display the current date and time, but i also want it to update the current time when the time changes.

then i hope to submit the datetime-local value to the database using PHP (i got this section covered)

and i was hoping if it's possible to delete the date and time selection button in the input and how can i show the seconds, but have the seconds running accurately with current time

thank you all.

```js
var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
document.getElementById('dt').value = now.toISOString().slice(0,16);
```

```html
<input id="dt" type="datetime-local" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can set an interval every second for this.

```js
 functionName(); //First execution
 setInterval(functionName, 1000); //Check every second

function functionName(){
   var now = new Date();
   now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
   document.getElementById('dt').value = now.toISOString().slice(0,16);
}
```

```html
<input readonly id="dt" type="datetime-local" />
```

Of course you will need to "Stop" this interval when the user clicks on the input, or the date can never be changed

EDIT: For avoid the user to change the date, just add readonly attribute to the input tag.

Comment: thank you for your help, but is there a way to avoid the need for the user to click the input to stop the interval and not update the date?

Comment: @s.alonzo I just edit my answer, you just need to add `readonly` to the input.

Comment: yes, that's what i thought of too, but i thought as well that it would still allow user to select date and time! thank you for that